# ApplySimple Formula for last year in Microstrategy Netezza syntax

Tags: netezza, microstrategy

I'd like some help to convert the following `applysimple` statement to it's netezza equivalent.

```
ApplySimple("(
   select top 1 tradyrcode
   from tradingyear
   where tradyrcode < (
      select max(tradyrcode)
      from yrdays yd, control c
      where c.systemdate = yd.datecode
   )
   order by 1 desc
)",0)
```

I think I need to change the `top 1` to `limit 1` for it to work in netezza.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where ‘top nn’ is at the beginning of the statement, ‘limit nn’ has to be at the very end, after a possible ‘order by’:

```
select tradyrcode
from trading-year
where tradyrcode < (
  select max(tradyrcode)
  from yrdays yd, control c
  where c.systemdate = yd.datecode
)
order by 1 desc
limit 1
```